# How to synchronize/link scrolling in two NSScrollView instances?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsscrollview

I have read and applied the [approach/method provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html) to synchronise two `NSScrollView` instances. My problem is even simpler as I only require synchronisation in one direction (not bi-directionally).

To summarise the approach: the "source" scrollView post bounds change notifications that are observed by a handler that calls the `scrollToPoint` method of the listening scrollview's clipview.

## The problem

While the second scrollView does synchronise with the first (eventually) there is an ever so slightly noticeable lag between the two. This is made worse for me because the listening `NSScrollView` contains headers that need to line up with the body content.

I have confirmed the lag by recording my scrolling actions at 30 fps and playing them back. Checking at that level of granularity it is very clear that the source scrollView starts to move way before the listening scrollView.

How do I get these two scrollViews to **truly** stay in sync with one another - is this possible or am I expecting to much?

Comment: This may be a consequence of responsive scrolling. Basically, the system is using the overdrawn area to show the scrolled-in area probably even before the bounds of the content view have been changed. Otherwise, I would expect that the scrolling operations would all be synchronous and draw in the same update pass. Try disabling responsive scrolling by overriding `+isCompatibleWithResponsiveScrolling` to return `NO` in either the scroll view or the content view. (I realize this may conflict with your desire to improve scrolling performance as expressed in your other questions.)

Comment: @KenThomases thanks, makes sense and I'm about to dive into the world of managed overdraw right now. See my indirect solution below - unfortunately it has an interesting unintended consequence of usage.

Comment: "the listening `NSScrollView` contains headers that need to line up with the body content" Do you maybe want a custom ruler view?

Comment: @KenThomases hmmm... I have never given rulers a single moments attention (there's a lesson in the dangers of naming things). I am trying to achieve spreadsheet column and row headers here and if (1) you can place your own view into them (2) they sync their scrolling with the body and (3) they are placed above the clipView => winner. Most worried about (1).

Comment: @KenThomases OK, added rulers to the headers. They meet the criteria in (3) but fall down in (2) because they don't sync (perfectly) with the content - there's a lag. Captured my scrolling at 30 fps to verify that. After that I didn't look into (1). I presume they are somehow managed outside of the "responsive scrolling" loop. Frustratingly close but as they say: "A miss is as good as a mile".

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem indirectly by using the `addFloatingSubview:` API of `NSScrollView`. However, this gives rise to other problems, namely that `scrollRectToVisible` is expected an unobscured `NSClipView`. This is documented in more detail in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153071/how-can-i-layout-my-clipview-relative-to-my-scrollview